# Is it possible to create a high quality watercolor effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-effects, brush

I am looking to create a high quality watercolor effect in illustrator. My question essentially is: **Is this created by scans and then tracing it? If so, what kind of tracing options would you use for that?**

Something like [this](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/watercolor-wedding-invitation_783152.htm#term=watercolor&page=1&position=3):

[image: Freepik Watercolor image]

*I'd like to note that this is not my image, I did not create this.*

When I downloaded the illustrator file and opened it, I wasn't expecting the background to be vector, because it looks so real. Inspecting it closer I found that it had a lot of points and was very detailed.

Is this created by using brushes? If so, what kind of brushes should I look for? 
All the ones I tried so far looked really fake and didn't have the speckling effect this one has, and I did not achieve a look as detailed as the one mentioned. I also tried making a real watercolor and scanning + tracing it but that leaves me with blotches of color, not the detailed points and specks in the given example.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need it as a vector?

Answer (score 2):

The basic process is fairly well [explained here](http://www.juneletters.com/blog/2014/10/20/tutorial-create-a-watercolor-effect-vector-logo).
**Bottom line:** Illustrator isn't good at *creating* watercolor effects.

### The best approach for a believable look

1. Use physical source material (a painting) to scan at 300dpi or higher (final size).
2. Choose a live trace setting that roughly achieves the effect — emphasis on the rough. You'll rarely get what you're after out of the box.
3. Play with the trace settings until you get the level of detail you're after.

### Tips for tracing options

- Modifying `Threshold` can produce wildly different results.
- `Max Colors` is the number of "swatches" the tracing will use. Increase this number until your gradations look natural.
- You want to include `Fills` but not `Strokes`.
- `Path Fitting` is going to adjust the amount of detail in your color transition boundaries.
- `Minimum Area` will impact the rendering of small edge areas and things like paint splatter.
- `Corner Angle` is often overlooked but can make a big difference in the realism of your transition areas. Low numbers will produce lots of sharp corners, which don't align with how paint absorbs into paper.

[image: Illustrator tracing options]

### Bad news

Your computer will crawl with high levels of detail.
The watercolor look requires high levels of detail.